# PyQt5 - very basics

Tags: python, pyqt5

This is a very basic program but I just want to understand how to display final result in GUI window? Now I am just printing it to check if its even works. I just don't know how to use result variable from function 'counting' and put it in initGUI function and display it to the user.

Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication,  QPushButton, QHBoxLayout, QInputDialog


class Calculator(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initGUI()


    def initGUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
        self.show()

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        adding = QPushButton('Adding', self)
        adding.clicked.connect(self.counting)

        layout.addWidget(adding)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def counting(self):

        num1, ok=QInputDialog.getInt(None, 'Type first value', 'here')
        num2, ok=QInputDialog.getInt(None, 'Type second value', 'here')
        result = num1 + num2
        print(result)



if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Calculator()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())`
```

Any advice? Should I use `QInputDialog` here or there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use QInputDialog but rather, say, QLineEdit. I would write it back into a label in the main widget. Like that for instance

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Calculator(QWidget):
    first = 0
    second = 0

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Calculator, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 300)
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)

        firstButton = QPushButton('Get first', self)
        firstButton.clicked.connect(self.get_first)

        secondButton = QPushButton('Get Second', self)
        secondButton.clicked.connect(self.get_second)

        thirdButton = QPushButton('Get Both', self)
        thirdButton.clicked.connect(self.get_both)

        layout.addWidget(firstButton )
        layout.addWidget(secondButton)
        layout.addWidget(thirdButton)

        self.resultLabel = QLabel()
        layout.addWidget(self.resultLabel)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def get_first(self):
        num1, ok=QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Type first value', 'here')
        if ok and num1:
            self.first = num1
        self.resultLabel.setText(str(self.first+self.second))

    def get_second(self):
        num2, ok = QInputDialog.getInt(self, 'Type second value', 'here')
        if ok and num2:
            self.second = num2
        self.resultLabel.setText(str(self.first + self.second))

    def get_both(self):
        self.get_first()
        self.get_second()

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Calculator()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```